# ¿Como adecuar un método de validación error provider a Textbox dentro de un Tabcontrol?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, textbox

Buen día, hasta ahora no usaba contenedores como tabcontrol, groupbox o panel, pero para organizar mejor uno de mis formularios decidí agregar un tabcontrol con 2 paginas. Usaba el siguiente método que a su vez se encuentra en otra clase para validar que los textbox que tuvieran en su propiedad tag la letra "V" no estuvieran vacíos al momento de intentar insertar en la base de datos

```
public static bool validarTextbox(Control.ControlCollection controles, ErrorProvider error)
    {
        bool exito = true;
        int numControles = controles.Count;

        Control control;

        for (int i = 0; i < numControles; i++)
        {
            control = controles[i];
            if (control is TextBox)
            {
                if (control.Tag != null && control.Tag.ToString().Equals("V"))
                {
                    if (((TextBox)control).Text.Equals(""))
                    {
                        error.SetError(control, "Dato obligatorio");
                        exito = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        error.SetError(control, "");
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
        return exito;
    }
```

Y en en mi botón guardar el código para llamar al método que tengo en otra clase es el siguiente

```
 bool exito = validar.validarTextbox(this.controls, errorDatos);
        if (!exito)
        {

            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
            return;
        }
```

Como comentaba en cuanto agregue el tabcontrol y fui agregando ahí los textbox, este código dejo de funcionar, estuve revisando en el sitio preguntas relacionadas y encontré un código que me esta funcionando que es el siguiente (este método y el código que pondré mas abajo que lleva mi botón guardar en el evento clic los tengo en el mismo formulario)

```
private IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(Control control)
    {
        var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();
        return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAllControls(ctrl)).Concat(controls);
    }
```

y en mi botón guardar el código es el siguiente, solo difiere del original que encontre en el sitio la parte donde revisa si la propiedad tag tiene la letra "V" ya que solo algunos de los controles son los que quiero validar y tambien agregue la parte para el numericupdown, y todo parece que funciona correctamente, sin embargo, la pregunta seria si ¿es posible adecuar el primer código que me funcionaba, para las situaciones cuando los controles estan dentro de tabcontrol o groupbox?, ese código me permitía accederlo desde cualquier formulario, y al momento de dar clic en los botones de guardar, validar que no estuvieran vacios los textbox que marcara su tag con "V". Si bien el ultimo código funciona, no veo como hacerlo mas genérico como el primero por así decirlo, en parte por mis muy básicos conocimientos en programación, por lo que cualquier aporte sera bien recibido, gracias.

```
 errorDatos.Clear();
        foreach (Control c in GetAllControls(this))
        {
            if ((c is TextBox && string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text)) && c.Tag.ToString().Equals("V"))
            {
                errorDatos.SetError(c, "no puede estar vacio");
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;

            }
            else if (c is NumericUpDown)
            {
                if (c.Tag != null && c.Tag.ToString().Equals("V"))
                {
                    if (((NumericUpDown)c).Value.Equals(0))
                    {
                        errorDatos.SetError(c, "Ingrese datos");
                        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hola, podrías hacerme saber si la respuesta dada te fue util

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los **TabControl** son controles que se componen de **TabPages**, estas **TabPages** son las que van a tener los controles que pongas, es decir un **TabControl** puede tener muchos **TabPages** y un **TabPage** puede tener muchos controles(**TextBox**, **ComboBox**, etcétera). Aclarado esto y aprovechando la idea que quieres llevar a cabo te propongo lo siguiente:

```
public static bool validarTextbox(TabControl tabControl, ErrorProvider error)
{
   foreach (TabPage tab in tabControl.TabPages)
   {
      foreach (Control control in tab.Controls)
      {
        if (control is TextBox)
        {
            if (control.Tag != null && control.Tag.ToString().Equals("V"))
            {
                if (((TextBox)control).Text.Equals(""))
                {
                    error.SetError(control, "Dato obligatorio");
                    exito = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    error.SetError(control, "");
                }
            }
         }
      }
   }

   return exito;
}
```

Ahora la función recibe como parámetro un **TabControl** y un **ErrorProvider**. Dentro de la función se ejecutan dos **ciclos foreach anidados**, el primero para recorrer los **TabPages** del **TabControl** y el segundo para recorrer los controles dentro de cada **TabPage**, después se preguntaría dentro del segundo ciclo si el control es un **TextBox** y de serlo vendrían entonces las validaciones que ya tenías hechas.

Respondiendo a lo que me preguntas del **GroupBox**, pues es lo mismo:

```
   foreach (TabPage tab in tabControl.TabPages)
   {
      foreach (Control control in tab.Controls)
      {
        if (control is TextBox)
        {
           //Tu código de validación
        }
        else if(control is GroupBox)
        {
           foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
           {
              if(c is TextBox)
              {
                 //Igualmente aqui tu código de validación
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

Que hay de nuevo en este código pues ahora además de preguntar si hay **TextBox** en los **TabPages**, también vas a preguntar si hay **GroupBox**. Y en caso de haber **GroupBox**, pues vas a recorrer con otro **foreach** los controles dentro de este **GroupBox** y preguntar si dentro de este **GroupBox** hay **TextBox**, de haber **TextBox**, pues a validarlos con tu código de validación.

Comment: Funciona, ahora ya me encuentra los textbox vacíos marcados con "V" en su tag en cualquier page. Adicional a eso habría manera de que si agrego un groupbox en alguna page, me recorra ese control también en busca de textbox vacíos?

Comment: @IsaAC, ya edite la respuesta y puse lo nuevo que preguntas, por favor si la respuesta te ha sido util no olvides marcarla como aceptada y darle un voto positivo, gracias

Comment: gracias por el apoyo, es justo lo que necesitaba, ya di clic en respuesta aceptada, lo del voto positivo como es?